# How to make scroll down clicking my arrow with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

**Hi guys hope you can help me well, thanks in advance for your time!, here's the thing:** I have this Website test and I just want to animate the scroll down when I click on the button, to make it like this one: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

---

I want the scroll stoped when the windows finish like the example and also a good ease animation for it.

---

**THINGS YOU MAY KNOW**: I know anything about jquery so I'm suffering trying to make this thing, so... please try to explain me like a child, or give me the code so I can implement it.

---

thanks, cheers!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>
  <style>
  div.demo {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="button"><button id='upClick'>Go Down</button></div>
<div class="demo"><h1>lalala</h1><p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?""At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."



</p></div>

 
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($("div").scrollTop( 1000 ));
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work the code properly I've added a new div with id `scroll` to scroll to

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $($(this).attr('data-target')).offset().top-50
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.navbar{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;  
   padding: 10px 20px;
   
}
.navbar button{
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  padding:7px 20px;
  border:none;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#fff;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.content{
  height:500px;
  margin:0;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
<button class="navtab" data-target="#div1">Div 1</button>
<button class="navtab" data-target="#div2">Div 2</button>
<button class="navtab" data-target="#div3">Div 3</button>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="content">
  <br><br>
  <h2>DIV 1</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="content">
  <h2>DIV 2</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="content">
  <h2>DIV 3</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```

Comment: really thanks! this is what I was looking for! but now I need a more elegant transition for the animation like the one in the link I attach above in the post do you have a recommendation?

Comment: do mean for multiple `div`s and navigations ?

Comment: no I'm just saying the transition, an ease transition, not "slow"

Comment: for design purpose im implementing that code in another page im designing and I dont like that transition, I want a better one more ease in ease out

Comment: Check this [link](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://api.jquery.com/animate/&ei=Zljs0Kg0&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=764&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1470373205&sig=AKOVD66Mla9rr9n7MFLhuO_gsHDNxaOu-Q)